# Terraform: create GitHub Organization Repository instead of a user repository

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-github

TF File structure:

- ./

  - main.tf (see code below, github provider defined here)
  - **module1** (folder)

    - module1.tfvars
    - github-repos.tf (see code below)
    - main.tf (blank)
    - variables.tf (defined for the module, value comes from tfvar file)
  - **module2** (folder)
  - **module3** (folder)

I have setup the GitHub integration in my root `main.tf` file like so:

**./main.tf**

```
terraform {
required_version = ">= 1.0.9"
backend "s3" {
}
required_providers {
github = {
source = "integrations/github"
version = "~> 4.0"
}
}
}

provider "github" {
owner = "githuborgname"
base_url = "https://github.com/githuborgname/" # we have GitHub Enterprise
token = github_mgmt_token
}
```

The `github_mgmt_token` is coming from an output later in the same `main.tf` file and seems to be working well (since the repo is getting successfully created under the PAT user repos).

Inside a module I have a `github-repos.tf` file that looks like so:
**./moduel1/github-repos.tf**

```
resource "github_repository" "ssc" {
name = "ssc"
description = "text"
homepage_url = "https://internalurl.com"
visibility = "private"
delete_branch_on_merge = true
auto_init = true
gitignore_template = "Python"
archive_on_destroy = true
vulnerability_alerts = true
}
```

This successfully creates the repo without issue but its inside the PAT user account instead of the GitHub org.

***How do you create an organization repo?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug with `1.0.9` & `1.0.10` (at the least, maybe other versions too), if I provide the `$GITHUB_OWNER` or `$OWNER` env var when running the Terraform apply, this works as expected and creates the repo in the org. For some reason it does not honor/see/understand the provider arguments as expected in these versions.

Comment: Is there a Github issue reported for the provider?
If so, it would be good to have it linked here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the `owner` argument to the provider:

> owner - (Optional) This is the target GitHub organization or individual user account to manage. For example, torvalds and github are valid owners. It is optional to provide this value and it can also be sourced from the GITHUB_OWNER environment variable. When not provided and a token is available, the individual user account owning the token will be used. When not provided and no token is available, the provider may not function correctly.

taken from https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs

i.e.

```
provider "github" {
  token = var.token
  owner = "myorg"          // <--- here
}
```

Comment: I have that on the first line of the provider GitHub? Or are you saying it must be directly below the token argument?

Comment: No. The order doesn't matter.

Comment: And you're right. I missed that. My answer doesn't make sense (as you already have it).

Comment: I know the docs say the `base_url` is mandatory with Github Enterprise. But you seem to be using cloud version anyway. Can you try without `base_url`?

Comment: Tested that, it just doesn't seem to get honored through the config. I have it working now with ENV VARs so I'm going to post a potential answer until a bugfix is out.